# Given 3 is a generator of $U(14)$, what is $\phi(11)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\phi$ be an automorphism of $U(14)$, with $\phi(3)=5$.  Given that 3 is a generator of U(14), what is $\phi(11)$?

What I've done:

$U(14)=\{1,3,5,9,11,13\}$

$U(14)=<3>$

$|U(14)|=6$

Should I calculate the number of generators?  Will that help me?  I need to understand what $\phi(3)=5$ is telling me and how it will help find $\phi(11)$.

Thank you!

Comment: note that $3^4=11\mod 14$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess by $U(14)$ you mean $(\Bbb{Z}/14)^\times$. Since $\phi$ is an automorphism, $\phi(3^n)=\phi(3)^n=5^n$. So if you find some $n$ such that $3^n=11$ you will know $\phi(11)$.

Comment: so based on this information, $\phi(11)=4$.  Correct?

Comment: Well $4 \notin U(14)$ so that is impossible. But $3^4=11$ so $\phi(11)=11^4=9$.

Comment: I understand your previous statement but how did you get 9?  Sorry - I don't know why I'm not seeing this!!

Comment: Oops, I made a typo, it's $5^4=9$.

Comment: i get it! Thank you so much!